# Mockito not using value in constructor when getter called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit-jupiter

I have the following Pojo:

```
public class Football extends Item {
    public Football(Colour colour, Double price ) {
        super(colour, 18.99);
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

}
```

I thought that when I created my mock in unit test as such:

```
@Mock
Football football;

@BeforeEach
private void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}
```

When I call the method `getPrice()` on my football mock - I should get `18.99` back as the price is hardcoded in the constructor params. However I do not.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what's supposed to happen.

A mock is an object where all the methods (with some documented exceptions) have been replaced EITHER

- by a method that does nothing, and returns either null, zero, false or empty, depending on the method's return type; OR
- by a method whose behaviour and return value you've specified yourself, via stubbing the method.

This includes the `getPrice` method in your example.  It's been replaced by a method that does nothing and returns `0.0`.

In Mockito, methods whose return types are

- primitive types, like `double`, `int` and so on,
- wrapper types, like `Double`, `Integer` and so on,

will return the appropriate kind of zero/false, if you haven't stubbed them to do otherwise.